# DFS algorithm vs Parent-child in tree category

Tags: algorithm

I need to implement a category tree like this:

```
laguages
.... Web
........ PHP
........ Python
........ HTML
.... System
........ C
........ C++
........ GO
........ RUST
```

So I have a table like this:

```
id | title | parent_id 
1  | system| 0
2  | c     | 1
3  | c++   | 1
4  | rust  | 1
5  | web   | 0
6  | php   | 5
7  | python| 5
8  | html  | 5
```

If i want to implement tree structure I have two solutions.

1. using a recursive function and create a parent-child array
2. using
   DFS search to make this structure that I need to add `left` and
   `right` column in the database table.

So my question is: what is deferences between this two solutions? and which one is better?

Comment: I don't see why you need either a recursive function or DFS. Just create an array of "Node" elements, each having a list of "children", and add the current node to the parent's children list. (I.e. a recursive data structure, but not a recursive function)

Comment: I heard using DFS has more performance advantage than recursive data structure. is it correct?

Comment: DFS is a search method, while a recursive data structure is ... a structure. They are two different things: you can do DFS in a recursive data structure. BTW: left-right columns would represent a binary tree, not the tree you have depicted. BTW2: a DFS is most often implemented as a recursive function, so they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=adjacency+list+vs+nested+set

Answer (score 0):

If the **search operations** will be more frequent, I would suggest *array based approach* because of the advantage of random access. In tree based structures, the search operations tend to be ***O(height)*** costly and the best height for balanced trees is ***O(log n)***.

On the contrary if **update operations** are more frequent, then I would go for *Tree-based* approach, since insertion and deletion is not very efficient in arrays due to shifting of elements involved.

**Custom Approach**

My Approach would have been the **[adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)** data structure if, your child arrays `Web` or `System` are reasonably small. One could access the list for `Web` or `System` in constant time **O(1)** . Coming to deletion *linked lists* overcome *arrays* in case of insertion and deletions, and since the lists are not that long, search wont cause that much of problem time-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the three structure isn't more than what you described (2 levels) and not n levels isn't a right question but one of things you should have in mind.
in php =script language we do it much simple(the case of 2 levels) :

```
<?php
$source=Array(' system',Array(' php   ',' c++   ',' html  '),' web   ',Array(' c     ',' rust  ',' python'));
function br(){echo('<br>');}
function printr($ar){
    if(is_array($ar)){
        foreach($ar as $key){
            print('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|____'.$key);
            br();
        }
    }else{
        print('['.$ar.']');br();
    }
    
    return true;
}
array_map("printr", $source);
?>
```

the output:

```
[ system]
   |____ php
   |____ c++
   |____ html
[ web ]
   |____ c
   |____ rust
   |____ python
```

this array :

```
$source=Array(
' system',
Array(' php   ',' c++   ',' html  '),
' web   ',
Array(' c     ',' rust  ',' python')
);
```

you should obtain it with a "generator" input from a form ,from a internal file created with another generator (web,compiler any kind)...

the maximum results comes when perfect input optimizations is stored in a intelligent structure can avoid use of LOTS CALCULATIONS ,Iterations( DFS algorithm or Parent-child  or any OTHER method)

```
/*
Also using of serialize
functions you can store an entirely array,
unserialize will help you to restore your array
*/


$source=unserialize($from_a_table_1_row_forever);
//   $from_a_table_1_row_forever=obtained from some your function to read it from a database,file ...etc
//now is good to use in memory,i mean that multi array


//when you want to store changes in some generator:
$for_a_table_1_row_forever=serialize($source);
good_to_write_it_in_a_single_table_row($for_a_table_1_row_forever);
//   (some your function to write in a database,file ...etc)
```